# How do I use map over a list with do notation - ie avoid type `IO ()' with type `[IO ()]'?

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad

So this question is about Monads more generally (in particuar for Fay), but my example uses the IO monad.

I have a function where the input is a list of strings and I would like to print each string one by one. So here was my idea:

```
funct :: [String] -> ?
funct strs = do
    map putStrLn strs
```

But doesn't work because it returns a type [IO ()]. So my question is, how would I map over a list, and treat it as if I'm performing the function line by line, in typical do-notation, iterative style (like below)?

```
funct :: [String] -> IO ()
funct strs = do
    putStrLn (strs !! 0)
    putStrLn (strs !! 1)
    ...
```

Comment: Use standard functions from `Control.Monad` already suggested. Also, could use `funct (h:t) = do { putStrLn h; funct t; }; funct _ = return ()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most of the standard library list functions have monadic versions that end with `M`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]

replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
replicateM :: (Monad m) => Int -> m a -> m [a]
```

etc.  Sometimes they are in `Prelude`, sometimes they are in the `Control.Monad`.  I recommend using [hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle) to find them.

Specifically for your case, i use `mapM_ putStrLn` quite often.

Comment: For bonus points, a good exercise is to read the documentation for `Control.Monad` and figure out on one's own how to write each of these functions.

Answer (score 6):

Use sequence

```
sequence $ map putStrLn strings
```

sequence pulls the monad out of a list of monads

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

thus converting (map putStrLn strings)::[IO a] to IO [a].  You might want to use the related sequence_ to drop the return value also.

You can also use `forM_:: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m ()` (which often looks nicer, but has a bit of an imperative feel to me).

Comment: `sequence . map f` is contained in the library as `mapM f`.